# Need constant sized type to send over sockets as header for non-constant data

Tags: python, sockets, protocols

As I learned the hard way today, Python does not have standardized type widths. An integer could be 20 bytes over here and 30 bytes over there. This presents an issue since I'm attempting to send a video stream over sockets. Each frame is a different size, so I decided to calculate the size of each frame and send that before the frame so the receiving program would know what to expect, but since Python's types aren't constantly sized, that won't work.

I attempted using the c types library, but I don't believe it's what I need, because in order to send it over the socket it would need to be bytes. (Obtained through `str(x).encode()`, I believe.)

cameraServer.py

```py
import cv2
import sys
import socket

host = ''
port = 4001
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("Preparing webcam.")
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
empty, frame = vid.read()
print("Webcam ready, waiting for client connection.")

sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(3)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print(addr, " connected, sending first frame size.")
conn.send(str(sys.getsizeof(cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring())).encode())

while True:
    if vid.isOpened():
        empty, frame = vid.read()
        data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()

        conn.send(str(sys.getsizeof(data)).encode())
        conn.send(data)
```

cameraClient.py

```py
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np

ip = "localhost"
port = 4001
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(3)

sock.connect((ip, port))

buff = sock.recv(24)
print("First frame size received! ", buff.decode(), "\n")

while True:
    frameSize = sock.recv(16)

    buff = sock.recv(int(frameSize.decode()))

    nparr = np.frombuffer(buff, np.uint8)
    newFrame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow("s", newFrame)
```

Comment: The size of a Python object has no relevance for network communication. It doesn't make sense to just take the raw memory bytes representing a Python object and shove them over the wire. Those bytes include stuff like the type pointer and the refcount, which make no sense on the receiving end. Also, there's no API to get those raw bytes anyway.

Comment: Calling `str` and `encode` on an int gets you a UTF-8 encoding of a *decimal string representation* of an int. Of course that's going to be variable-size. It'd be variable-size no matter whether you did it in Python, did something equivalent with `itoa` or `sprintf` or something in C, or constructed that decimal string in any other language.

Comment: The size of a Python object does have relevance. I need the client to know how many bytes to read (the size of a standardized integer) to get the number of bytes in the next frame of the video stream.

Comment: But the object size reported by `sys.getsizeof` is a completely different number from the number of bytes you're going to send.

Comment: Oh, is there a function to check for the amount of bytes taken up by a specific variable?

Comment: You don't need standardized object sizes. The number of bytes in any object you will ever transfer will be less than 2**64. Therefore, you can use `struct.pack()` with the "Q" specifier to create an 8 byte length for sending on the socket (use `struct.unpack()` on the receiving side), or you can just use `objLength.to_bytes(8, 'big', signed=False')` to send, where `objLength` is the int containing the length of the object.

Comment: I ended up resolving the problem in a different way, but this is still very good information, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the frames actually *are* a constant size, so now this line is all it takes.
`buff = sock.recv(921664)`

Comment: That will not be reliable. Look at the docs, `recv(bufsize)` returns **at most** *bufsize* bytes, not exactly *bufsize* bytes.